# Weka CSV to Arff conversion : IllegalArgumentException: Attribute names are not unique

Tags: weka

I have a Csv file download from http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/index.html. I need to convert it to arff file format.

I tried running

```
java weka.core.converters.CSVLoader /home/saket/Documents/Assignment/NIST7000 > /home/saket/Documents/Myfile.arff
```

but it's giving following error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attribute names are not unique! Causes: '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0'
```

Then I tried using http://weka.wikispaces.com/Converting+CSV+to+ARFF java code. BUt still same error came.

Can someone please suggest what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There was no header fields in the csv. So I created a script and added column0,column1,...,class in the Csv file first line. 
Then opened that generated csv file in weka.

Comment: You should be able to use CSV files without header by using the `-H` option, i.e. `loader.setOptions(new String[] {"-H"});`

Answer (score 4):

I have encountered the same exception but with a different reason. I used "class" as the attribute name, but this word also appeared in my data as a string (after @data) and Weka did not correctly separate attribute and data.
Solved by simply renaming "class" attribute to something else like "s_label".

Comment: similar problem and solution https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/207935-Weka-text-classification/

Answer (score 0):

It happens when attribute name is same, in more than one column of the excel sheet. Just rename the column name which are same. It should be unique.I changed my third column name, which was same.Please have a look in screenshot attached.This can be done via an script too for large set of dataset. This worked for me.[image]

[image]